# $captcha->CheckAnswer() always returns false

Tags: joomla-3.x, login, captcha

After a lot of struggle, I've figured out how to implement the standard Joomla reCaptcha.

But now **my problem** is the verifying of it on the server side.

The steps of the reCaptcha:

1. I have a form with the recaptcha implemented like this **(works fine)**:

   ```
   $captcha_plugin = JFactory::getConfig()->get('captcha');
   if ($captcha_plugin != '0') {
       $captcha = JCaptcha::getInstance($captcha_plugin);
       $field_id = 'captcha';
       print $captcha->display($field_id, $field_id, 'g-recaptcha');
   }
   ```
2. On submit I send an AJAX call to this url **(works fine)**:

   `'index.php?option=com_content&format=ajax&view=article&task=loginUser&tmpl=component'`
   It's a file I've made inside com_content > views > article
3. The code in my `loginUser` task / function (**not validating**, see end of question)

   ```
   public function _logInUser( $form ){
       $captcha_plugin = JFactory::getConfig()->get('captcha');
       $captcha = JCaptcha::getInstance($captcha_plugin);
       $completed = $captcha->CheckAnswer($form[2]['value']);
       var_dump($form);
       echo $form[2]['value'];
       var_dump($completed);
       die();
   ```

Update: I've also tried like this, still gives me `false` when it should return true:

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$res = $dispatcher->trigger('onCheckAnswer',$form[2]['value']);
if(!$res[0]){
    var_dump($res);
    die('Invalid Captcha');
}
var_dump($res);
die();
```

---

`echo $form[2]['value'];` returns "" when captcha is not clicked and returns something like this when clicked: "`03AMGVjXgaSV3U5UnezVUIFslFElvrMDe2gOVoJtEwtT9SVMaqG47cyC16CPrl01H3yKVF1y4aaBOnK-E1AeBa1H8XoBE17fN-8L3j0_W5mvO8g9kbrVg-yYEuk1B9lSTWxYfn9kf23yPTY-wlIOijh04vqBwUTLFoiTL-Jw9Ae-l2uvgVrnb1qyBrYt5dtvfRWvwbAx6h6qGXh4WBZz19eFkTv5mTmheGsp4s-5e-VtiqMEQJynNxE0fjxqQxKNyCECAK6SRbtLdZ8NTlDAG4dOd4zfb-R2aIYxwvPOxLjxrlO_5xggTOwqA`"

So it must be working.

but this line always returns *false* : `$completed = $captcha->CheckAnswer($form[2]['value']);`

and when removing `$form[2]['value']` in `$captcha->CheckAnswer`

I get this output:

*Warning: Missing argument 1 for Joomla\CMS\Captcha\Captcha::checkAnswer(), called in /customers/a/c/e/test-mysite.dk/httpd.www/test/components/com_content/views/article/view.ajax.php on line 35 and defined in /customers/a/c/e/test-mysite.dk/httpd.www/test/libraries/src/Captcha/Captcha.php on line 192
Notice: Undefined variable: code in /customers/a/c/e/test-mysite.dk/httpd.www/test/libraries/src/Captcha/Captcha.php on line 200*

**INFO UPDATE for future readers!:**
Joomla does NOT provide reCaptcha for the login form. Only for the registration and contact form. I've found it here: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=910764

Comment: Any warnings or errors generated from `JFactory::getConfig()->get('captcha')` or `JCaptcha::getInstance($captcha_plugin)` or `$captcha->CheckAnswer($form[2]['value'])`?  Have you got debugging turned all the way up?

Comment: Yes it's set to developer mode. I´ve added all the errors to my question

Comment: No, I mean with your originally posted attempt -- any warnings/error with that?

Comment: ahh!... no that gives me no errors, only the false output of `CheckAnswer`

Comment: How about in the backend... In `Global Configuration` > `Contacts`, go to tab `Form` and set `Allow Captcha on Contact` to `captcha-recaptcha` and `Global Configuration` > `Users`, go to `User Options` tab and set `Captcha` to `captcha-recaptcha` .  Then clear cache / have a fresh go and let me know how that stacks up.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa I’ll try it as soon as I can!

Comment: @mickmackusa Just checked it. It was already set to those values and global default captcha was also set to `captcha-recaptcha`. The system cache is set to `OFF`.

Comment: Hmm, more research required.  You don't have any more clues? Have you tested the recaptcha configuration to be successful under normal implementation?

Comment: Ah! actually it dosen't show up in the login page when I remove my override of the login page. No warnings though. I think I'll try to install a fresh Joomla on a subdomain and see if I can get it to work just as the normal reCaptcha :(... The only thing I can think off is that I have J2 store installed and that have a plugin for captcha(but the plugin is disabled, so should be that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist of all, **PHP is case sensitive**. This means that `CheckAnswer` and `checkAnswer` is not the same (note the capital c).

The correct usage is `$captcha->checkAnswer('your_captcha_id')`.

What's the problem with your approach:

You are passing the captcha's post result as the ID of your captcha.

Since you have used `captcha` as the `$field_id` when you included the captcha, you should write `$captcha->checkAnswer('captcha')` to check the answer.

Comment: hmmmm... Still gives me `false` but this really seem to be the right solution... The strange thing is that I can´t get the reCaptcha to work just as standard inplementation. I'll try to install a fresh Joomla now and see if I can get it to work... Thanks for your answer! I'll let you know what happens

Comment: Just found out that Joomla does not provide the captcha for the login form out of the box. I found it here: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=910764 ....I will try to copy my files over to a new installation and see if your answer works! :)

Comment: I did a lot of testing and trying! I simply can't get it to work :( I managed to get the default Joomla captcha to work on registration and contact forms - so it is installed correctly. But testing my own implementation with your corrections, still gives me a `bool(false)` response

Comment: I've accepted this answer as I found out that if I moved the script to a custom plugin rater than inside com_content > views > article. Then your answer did work!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out after all @JonasB

Answer (score 1):

Never got it to work with Joomla's `$captcha->checkAnswer()`.

So instead, I've omitted Joomla's checking solution and went straight with Google's checking API.

Here's the code I'm successfully using for the checking part:

```
$secretKey = "my_secret_key";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$form[2]['value']."&remoteip=".$ip);
var_dump($response);
```

`$form[2]['value']` is the response from the reCaptcha